# Is the photograph "England’s Revenge in India" real, staged, or fake?

Tags: india, british-empire, historiography, photography

Might have an interesting puzzle for you here…

This picture, titled "England's Revenge in India", appeared in [a Nazi propaganda book against Britain published in 1941](http://research.calvin.edu/german-propaganda-archive/raub.htm):

[image: "England's Revenge on India" from the 1941 Nazi propaganda book "Robber State England"]

The propaganda book claims that this is a photograph from 1857, published in the English newspaper Picture Post in 1939. (Note that the captions/titles on the linked page are literal extracts from the book, not research by the author, merely translated by him from German.)

It bears a very close resemblance to [this Vasily Vereshchagin painting from 1884](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Vereshchagin-Blowing_from_Guns_in_British_India.jpg):

[image: Vasily Vereshchagin: Blowing from Guns in British India]

What is going on here? I see three possibilities:

1. The photo is genuine, and the painting traces the photo.
2. The photo is staged, and the painting traces the photo.
3. The painting came first, and the "photo" is the painting with some clever pre-digital photo editing.

However I'm really stumped as to which one is the answer. I can't find any reference to a 1939 Picture Post photo with that title, but Picture Post is a very well known and well archived publisher.

The Wikipedia page ["Blowing from a gun"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blowing_from_a_gun) features the painting and alleges that the image is anachronistic — that the British soldiers are wearing the wrong uniform for the alleged age of the incident. Note that the photograph has the same uniforms, so if true, that would indicate that either the photograph is staged or that it is an edit of the painting.

P.S.: Just to be clear, I'm not denying any of the numerous horrific crimes of the British Empire upon India. I'm purely curious about the origins of this strange photograph.

Comment: Ah, sorry. It's from the second link- might be that you have to visit it first and get some kind of session or cookie before they let you direct link?

Comment: That picture makes me very sad. I think the question is fine though

Comment: Thanks for the edit, much better. The question is just: Where did this photograph from the propaganda piece come from? Is it a genuine photograph, or staged, or fake?

Comment: To me it looks like the b&w version is just a photograph of the painting. I don't see where any kind of confusion could arise - that is, do you see any difference between the images that would not immediately be explained by the b&w effect, some loss of detail and such?

Comment: It could also easily have been the case that the painting was a trace of the photograph, particularly as all copies of the painting are very poor quality / vague. But given sempaiscuba's answer, I think it is clear that it is a photograph of the painting (with some manipulation: buildings in the distance less apparent, sky more natural looking). Also, though I was leaning strongly towrad the photo being fake, it was such a preposterous proposition that I had to be sure others would come to the same conclusion.

Comment: The fact that the Western Powers acted like absolutely horrible oppressive assholes during the so-called "Colonial Era" is news to exactly zero people who have *ever* read an actual history book.

Comment: Definitely **not** a photograph of a live scene.  The captives would have struggled against their bindings and they, at least, would have been blurred.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

It seems to be the painting [Suppression of the Indian Revolt by the English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blowing_from_a_gun#/media/File:Vereshchagin-Blowing_from_Guns_in_British_India.jpg), a painting by the Russian artist [Vasily Vereshchagin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vasily_Vereshchagin) c. 1884

According to the annotation on Wikipedia:

> It anachronistically depicts the events of 1857 with soldiers wearing
> (then current) uniforms of the late 19th century.

The "photograph" originally appeared in a 1941 Nazi book titled *Raubstaat England* (*"Robber State England"*). It is one of a collection of propaganda images that was published in a collection titled [Visual Nazi Propaganda (Artwork in magazines)](https://dlscrib.com/queue/visual-nazi-propaganda-artwork-in-magazines_588e22b96454a76d7035c067_pdf?queue_id=5ef36f8ae2b6f5152989f51e) by 'Hagur'. That particular image, together with the text from the 1941 publication, is on page 107.

I've found a number of sites, like this one about an [exhibition at Tate Britain](http://www.thirdtext.org/allday-artist-empire), that reproduce the picture, and describe it simply as a "black-and-white reproduction" of Vasily Vereshchagin's painting.

The photogravure image used in *Raubstaat England* may have been taken from [this print in the Library of Congress Prints and Photos Collection](http://cdn.loc.gov/service/pnp/cph/3c10000/3c17000/3c17400/3c17473v.jpg) produced by the American Art Association of New York. If so, they were probably using it in breech of copyright, but given the scale of Nazi crimes during the 1940's ...

---

The method of execution [Blowing from a gun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blowing_from_a_gun) was certainly used by the British in India, and also by the Portuguese and even the [Mughal Empire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mughal_Empire). We know that it was used on convicted rebels in the aftermath of the [Indian Rebellion of 1857](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_Rebellion_of_1857#Deathtoll_and_atrocities). However, [British Army field uniforms](https://i.pinimg.com/736x/33/75/a7/3375a70d2302e06247507857d109cbc8--british-uniforms-indian-army.jpg) in 1857 were indeed very different from those depicted in the painting.

The East India Company was formally dissolved, and its ruling powers in India transferred to the British Crown by the [Government of India Act 1858](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Government_of_India_Act_1858).

---

The [archive](http://www.gale.com/c/picture-post-historical-archive) from the Picture Post is published online and is searchable. I have searched from 1938 - 1940 and could not find the image. Searching for the picture by title and by artist obtained no results.

It is worth noting that the [Picture Post](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picture_Post) was a liberal, anti-Fascist publication which had campaigned against the persecution of Jews by Nazi Germany since it was founded in 1938. It is entirely possible that this was propaganda directed against both the British and the magazine.

Comment: 1. I think the uniform of the top left soldier on [this picture](https://i.pinimg.com/736x/33/75/a7/3375a70d2302e06247507857d109cbc8--british-uniforms-indian-army.jpg) is the same as the artillerists' on the picture of the question. 2. I've seen this photo first time as part of the history courses of the elementary education of an "eastern block" state. And the commies typically didn't like to take over PR from the nazis (even if it was useful for them - simply nobody wanted to take the responsibility in the relevant decision-makers).

Comment: @MorningStar The helmet is the wrong shape in that picture. The webbing is also wrong. It is closer to the top left soldier in [this picture](https://i.pinimg.com/736x/80/f8/ea/80f8ea4ca19c81788ada2b37813b800f--army-uniform-military-uniforms.jpg). It is often claimed that the picture represents the execution of Maulvi Baqir in 1857, although that isn't the title given to the picture by the (Russian) artist, Vasily Vereshchagin.

Comment: I've not been able to find a genuinely high resolution colour version of the painting. All high res colour images appear to be upscaled versions of a low resolution photo, which may explain why the colour version looks more like a painting than the black and white version. Overlaying them definitely gives the impression that the are exactly the same image (bar the building in the top left which defies explanation). As you say, most places describe the black and white version as a "black-and-white reproduction".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93228/discussion-between-sempaiscuba-and-justcal).

Comment: The link to archive.org's Visual Nazi Propaganda. appears to be defunct. Can you find an alternative?

Comment: Was it this by 'Hagur' https://dlscrib.com/download/visual-nazi-propaganda-artwork-in-magazines_588e22b96454a76d7035c067_pdf ?

Comment: @LаngLаngС Yep, that seems to be it (or, at least, it has the right title and the image appears on the correct page).

Answer (score 19):

[Radio Yerevan reports](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radio_Yerevan_jokes) that: "In principle, yes, the photo is absolutely real. Except, that it isn't a real photo, its name isn't 'England's Revenge in India', and the propaganda book never claimed any of that". (See end of post for a quick resolution)

## The picture in the question has a wrong description at the German Propaganda Archive, it is also not a photo originally

The educational site [German Propaganda Archive](http://research.calvin.edu/german-propaganda-archive/raub.htm) (GPA) hosted by Calvin College makes *crucial* mistakes in presenting the picture and describing it. In modern terms: the metadata is mixed up. [As this remains utterly wrong as on the Alamy](https://www.alamy.com/this-is-a-black-and-white-reproduction-of-blowing-from-guns-in-british-india-1-2-this-particular-reproduction-was-used-in-raubstaat-england-a-1941-anti-british-propaganda-leaflet-issued-by-the-nazis-3-it-appeared-in-that-leaflet-with-the-following-factually-untrue-caption-this-1857-photograph-was-published-in-1939-by-the-english-newspaper-picture-post-it-shows-the-methods-used-to-suppress-the-sepoy-rebellion-as-an-english-eyewitness-noted-at-the-time-the-executions-occurred-summarily-and-without-appeal-blowing-from-guns-in-british-india-1880s-1857-quotblowing-from-image184961615.html), or also wrong in "Visual Nazi Propaganda From Hagur’s Private Collection since 1998", © March 2013 – Skull Press Ebook Publications Ghent, Belgium (Non Commercial), ([PDF](https://dlscrib.com/download/visual-nazi-propaganda-artwork-in-magazines_588e22b96454a76d7035c067_pdf))

Why? The version in the GPA had evidently a switch between pictures and their captions on one double page, as perhaps the original owner seems to have confused the correct placement/position in his picture collection book on one double page.

## The original *two pictures* as published in 1941

If we look at the original Nazi book, the mix up on the American GPA site is evident, *as the original does not claim to show a photograph for "England's Revenge in India"; it has a different title and doesn't mention a magazine as source, but indeed just the Russian painter* originally:

> [image]
> [image]
> [image]
> [image]
> [image]
> click for larger images
> ([src for the last two pictures](https://germanpostalhistory.com/php/viewitem.php?itemid=33462))

The picture on the *left* is titled "England's Revenge *on* India" *"(Englands Rache *an* Indien)"* and it is sourced as 'published by the Picture Post, 3 Juni 1939'.
**On GPA the caption for this picture was used in error to describe the "photo or painting" in question.**

## What's going on here with three possibilities in the question to choose from?

Just: none of the above from the three possibilities presented by OP.

The 'photo' on the *right* page 77 is the one in question and in the Nazi book titled almost correctly as "Execution of rebellious Sepoys" *(Hinrichtung aufständischer Sepoys)* and *accurately* described as being a *painting* by Russian artist [Wassili](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vasily_Vereshchagin) [Wereschtschagin](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wassili_Wassiljewitsch_Wereschtschagin). The English title [Suppression of the Indian Revolt by the English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suppression_of_the_Indian_Revolt_by_the_English) [is rendered in German as *"Hinrichtung von Sepoys (1857)"*](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wassili_Wassiljewitsch_Wereschtschagin).

So, in the original source we have only a reproduction of a painting for publication, correctly described and attributed. No claim that it is a "photo", and no claim to the effect of having found *this* in an English magazine.

## The picture captioned "England's Revenge on India"

The actual photo titled in the book "England's Revenge on India", on the left of that double page, [is 'real'](https://ispad.tumblr.com/post/86406659658/a-public-hanging-of-freedom-fighters-in-british) to be ['real'](http://dissertationreviews.org/archives/12586) as well:

Source of that image:
According to [Sean Willcock, Postdoctoral Fellow, Paul Mellon Centre for Studies in British Art: "Colonial Photography in British India",  September 21, 2015:](http://dissertationreviews.org/archives/12586)

> [image]
> Image: Felice Beato, Two Sepoys of the 31st Native Infantry Who Were Hanged at Lucknow, albumen print from collodion-on-glass negative, June 1858. The J. Paul Getty Museum, Los Angeles.
> [Digital image courtesy of the Getty’s Open Content Program.](http://www.getty.edu/art/collection/objects/241644/felice-beato-execution-of-rebels-lucknow-british-1858/)

## Source attribution for "England's Revenge on India"

From where the Cigarette manufacturers got it for their Nazi propaganda book is unknown at the moment. But the claim that the *Picture Post* indeed did publish *this* picture with the hangings in mid-1939 is not disproven either.

Two studies that also analyse the book *Raubstaat* do not question the authenticity of any of the pictures used in that pamphlet. But both note the method of *how* they are used: by screwing with the context in which they appear and – ironically – giving sometimes tenuous descriptions or explanations.

> … show very little on their own, but rely entirely on the accompanying text for the damning narrative. The readers again have to complete these connections, and in so doing collude in the politicisation of the hobby.
> — Victoria Stiles: "Empire and national character: British imperialism in books from the 'Third Reich'", PhD thesis, University of Nottingham, 2015. ([PDF](http://eprints.nottingham.ac.uk/29297/1/STILES%20full%20thesis%20for%20hard%20binding.pdf))

> … recurring terms and themes are gruesomeness, sadism, torture, robbery, victims and loot, revenge, hypocrisy, unscrupulousness, greed and perfidious Albion. ‘Cant’ makes several appearances, introduced and explained with schoolmasterly care as an untranslatable term specific to English political hypocrisy: “das die politische Scheinheiligkeit des Engländers bezeichnet, ist daher nicht in anderen Sprachen übersetzbar.”   **Illustrations, particularly by Gillray and Hogarth, are carefully selected from English or French sources.** These included Punch and French satirical magazines (that often also had Germany in their sights): L’Assiette au Beurre (1901–36) and Le Carivari (1832–1937).
> — Catherine Mason: "Raubstaat England. The Long Reach of Colonial Resentment", Angermion, Volume 12: Issue 1, 2020. [doi](http://doi.org/10.1515/anger-2019-0004)

The [currently accepted answer](https://history.stackexchange.com/a/40270/26786) was misled into searching for a painting in the *Picture Post* archive despite the original source never claiming to have pulled it from there. The search was thus necessarily fruitless since it looked for the wrong picture. The propaganda booklet claimed that the picture of the hangings was from the *Picture Post,* not the execution-by-cannon.

[Whether *that* photo was also published in that magazine or not, we might find out in time.](https://history.stackexchange.com/q/52367/26786)
— *Update:* And as we can clearly see on that other post here on SE: it *was* published in the magazine of that name on the date as referenced, just like the Nazi booklet claimed.

**Propaganda doesn't work if you just lie as you like all the time.**

> **Q** Is the photograph “England’s Revenge in India” real, staged, or fake?

The photo *with that title* is real. But the photo with that title *isn't pictured* in the question. The picture from the question is a reproduction of a painting and properly declared as such in the question generating propaganda pamphlet.
No mystery there, just an error in the *German Propaganda Archive.*

From a picture usage viewpoint the Nazi pamphlet uses on these two specific pages just the very same pictures as the current Wikipedia page for [Indian Rebellion of 1857](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_Rebellion_of_1857), and almost in the same context, directly together:

> [image]

---

The [whole propaganda book is in an online version here](https://web.archive.org/web/20170724222117/https://germanenherz.wordpress.com/tag/raubstaat-england/), or as a [really horrible *audio*-book but with page-by-page illustration here.](https://donnersender.ru/v/4904)

In the original nazi-book we see again the correct placement of pictures and captions:

[image] [image]

> [image]
> Englands Rache an Indien Dieses Photo von 1857 wurde 1939 von der englischen Zeitschrift“ Picture Post“ veröffentlicht. Es zeigt die Methoden, mit denen die englischen Behörden nach der Niederwerfung des Sepoy-Aufstandes vorgingen. „Die Hinrichtungen von Eingeborenen geschahen ganz summarisch und wahllos“, berichtet ein englischer Augenzeuge.
> **(England's revenge on India. This photo from 1857 was published in 1939 by the English magazine Picture Post.** It shows the methods used by the English authorities after the defeat of the Sepoy uprising. "The executions of the natives were summary and indiscriminate", according to an English eyewitness.)

> [image]
> Hinrichtung aufständischer Sepoys. Für die Vollstreckung der massenhaften Todesurteile an den aufständischen indischen Soldaten erfanden die englischen Offiziere eine neue Hinrichtungsart: die Verurteilten wurden vor Kanonen gebunden und so „in die Luft geblasen“. Gemälde des russischen Malers Wassilij Wereschtschagin.
> (Execution of rebel sepoys. For the execution of the mass death sentences on the insurgent Indian soldiers, the English officers invented a new method of execution: the condemned were tied in front of cannons and thus "blown up". **Painting by the Russian painter Vasily Vereschagin.**)

### How did this error occur?

There are basically two possibilities:

The author of GPA, Bytwerk, might have just confused two pictures and their captions. But even more likely is that due to the nature of this book:
*Raubstaat England* started out as an [exhibition in Munich](https://books.google.com/books?id=KiCfAwAAQBAJ&lpg=PA317&dq=raubstaat%20england&pg=PA318). The pictures shown there were then distributed as [cigarette](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cigarette_card) [cards](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zigarettenbild) and the 'book' is then really only a collector's album. An album with accompanying text by [Ernst Lewalter](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ernst_Lewalter) in which each owner had to place the pictures by themselves. It stands to reason that Bytwerk was unlucky enough to work with a single copy in which the original owner misplaced the two images.

## Timeline of Events

- 1857 — [Sepoy Rebellion in India](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_Rebellion_of_1857), British victory, and 'methods of suppression'. — No photo, not even a picture close to what's in question exists for the 'blowing of guns', but one photo of two rebells hanging from the gallows is shot by Beato.
- 1882 — Vereshchagin decides to go to India

  > [He] did not stay true to the word not to write any more war stories. This time he turned to the subject of the suppression of the British revolt of the sepoys in 1857. The Indian uprising of mercenaries against the colonists employers last but not least been successfully suppressed due to the public executions that received a poetic name "the Devil's wind." In 1857, the newspaper the People's Rares these highly effective interventions are described as follows:
  >
  > > "The British in India invented a method of execution so horrific that all of humanity is shocked. Are these merciful Christians invented a subtle way – tied living people to the muzzles of the guns, and then fired, ripping people to pieces, spraying blood rain of the pieces of the human body and guts at the audience".
- 1884 — The painter comments on the picture:

  > When (two years after the return of the artist from India) painting "The suppression of the Indian uprising by the British" was written, Vereshchagin commented:
  >
  > > "Modern civilization has scandalicious mainly to the fact that the Turkish massacre was carried out close in Europe, and then the means of committing atrocities too reminded tamerlanovsky times: cut, slit her throat, just sheep. Another thing from the British: first, they were doing the work of justice, the matter of retribution for the violated rights of winners, far away, in India; secondly, did the thing Grand: hundreds tied rebelled against their rule and not of sepoys of the sepoys to the muzzles of guns and no projectile, one gunpowder, shot them is already a great success against pererezali throat or ripping the belly".
  >
  > — [Andrew Zimoglyadov: "The suppression of the Indian uprising by the British"](https://arthive.com/vasilyvasilyevichvereshchagin/works/396926%7EThe_suppression_of_the_Indian_uprising_by_the_British)
- 1939 — The 1857 photo by Beato is printed in the English magazine Picture Post
  <sub>([June 3, 1939, or not, verification pending!](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/52367/did-the-picture-post-publish-the-1857-photo-two-sepoys-of-the-31st-native-infan?noredirect=1&lq=1))</sub>
- 1939 — In Munich, Nazis organise an exhibition called "Robber State England", showing the painting by Vereshchagin: [image], and the photo by Beato
- 1941 — The pictures from the exhibition are assembled for inclusion into a book of the same name with accompanying text from Lewalter. The book is made in two forms: one is a collector's album for cigarette cards as this was the way the pictures were initially distributed, another version has just the finished book with pictures already included. In this book the picture is accurately sourced as being a reproduction of the painting, not a photo.
- post 1945 — Contents of the book end up as translated into English snippets, intended for showcasing German propaganda methods. Sometime at this stage pictures and captions from pages 76 and 77 of the book get confused and that error reproduced. At the latest. Perhaps one collector glued in the picture at the wrong place in the cigarette card collector's book version of the book, perhaps there were misprints.
- ~2008 — Randall Bytwerk uploads the wrong combination of Picture and caption to his page German Propaganda Archive
- Sep 16 '17 at 19:35 — Prompted by the wrong caption (which is also in some archives with wrong meta-data) that *now* claims the Vereshchagin painting to be 'a photograph copied from a 1939 English magazine', this thread starts.
- **June 24, 2020 — The [German Propaganda Archive is updated](https://research.calvin.edu/german-propaganda-archive/raub.htm) ([old version for comparison](https://web.archive.org/web/20200622150728/http://research.calvin.edu/german-propaganda-archive/raub.htm)) to correct the wrong caption, now showing that the picture in question is indeed just a painting by Vereshchagin, (that is: *not a photo from a 1939 magazine)***

Comment: Except, of course, that the picture wasn't actually published in the Picture Post (see my answer above)

Comment: @sempaiscuba Can#t trial that walled archive now. Do you still have access? (The date should be searchable with a little more focus now?)

Comment: No, my access expired at the end of last year.  I searched a year either side of the date given without a hit, so I'm guessing they just made up the attribution.

Comment: @sempaiscuba Just realised: for which picture did you scan? Only the gallows pic is attributed to the Picture Post, but I assume you looked for the cannons?

Comment: Yes.  If I remember correctly, there's also another picture in Raubstaat England that was attributed to Picture Post, but I couldn't find that one either.  Turns out Nazis were also liars!  Who knew?  ;-)

Comment: @sempaiscuba Bytwerk might have had a copy in which the collector mixed sth up. But the actual book? Dang, 761000 copies produced, not one online complete or in a library near me? As well as the PicPost, miles&more travel no distance loans, and then this frickin walled garden of these archives. Do you remember the other picture you searched? (Honestly, I would by now expect it to be actually in that magazine, but sigh…)

Comment: Not after more than 18 months.  I barely remember the _paid_ research I was doing 18 months ago!

Answer (score 3):

The state of the art in photography at the time would make such a photo impossible in any case.

All photographs had to be staged, the grain is too fine etc.  Many commercial painters could render a painting of that quality very quickly from sketches that would take only a few minutes.  There may have been several sketch artists working at the same time for newspapers to print. After their painters created an oil picture from sketches.  This would explain why the photograph has minor difference with this particular painting.  It was a photograph of a different painting.

Before photography was perfected many many artists made a living in exactly this manner.

The sepoy rebellion was a big deal in Britain. The army was astounded that British trained troops would behave in such a manner. That is why their revenge was so terrible.

Comment: Sources to support your assertions, particularly in regard to the state of the art in photography in 1941, would greatly improve this answer.

Comment: @sempaiscuba I believe Justin meant the state of photography in 1857, when the photograph was alledgedly taken. It's an interesting point. Nonetheless I'd be interested in a source for both that assertion, and the assertion regarding such paintings being created in minutes.

Comment: @Jansky, a sketch artist would create a line-art version of the scene in a few minutes; this would be handed over to an oil-paint artist who would take hours or days to produce the final version, filling in details from their imagination or from written descriptions.

Comment: @Jansky, state of the art for photography in 1857 was the [daguerrotype](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daguerreotype).  For a scene in direct sunlight such as the picture in the question, exposure times could be just a few seconds, and wouldn't require much staging, if any.  But since the daguerrotype process produces a positive image rather than a negative, daguerrotypes couldn't be reproduced with the technology of the time.

Answer (score 0):

From just looking at the two pictures, without historical context, I would say that

- the photograph came first
- the painting traces the photo not very
  well

The "painting" has too much of both detail and simplification where would not expect it. See the grainy ground around the shadow of the closest soldier? Some stones appear to be too sharp, but some fine structures are missing.

Also, **the painting changes the "church"-like building on the right**, just in front of the rightmost soldier at the front. It's altered in shape and in size.

It could be another question: why exactly this building was altered. Everything else seems to be very directly replicated.

Comment: The painting itself has been destroyed. The only digital copies of it we have are very poor quality, hence why the shadow is grainy etc. The building not being different is not a contradiction. Look at [the photograph of the painting that @sempaiscuba found](https://cdn.loc.gov/service/pnp/cph/3c10000/3c17000/3c17400/3c17473v.jpg). The hard flash of the camera has flushed out the darker shades of the painting, making it difficult to make out all but one spire of the odd building. This may well be the picture the Nazis used in their propaganda piece.

Comment: @Janski No flash can make a building bigger.

Comment: We know that the two images are of the same painting, and one has part of the building emitted while the other doesn't. And the photograph with the smaller building is very bright and washed out with white, which is exactly what you would expect from using too much flash.